# Pandas Dataframe comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 very large dataframes +20k rows. df_input and df_output.

**df_input** is made of test cases ;
**df_output** is filled with the results from those test cases.

I need to select all the case numbers which failed from df_output and then fix those cases in the df_input dataframe. The fix is selecting a **new unique date for each case_id**.

To select a new unique date it has to be within 7*k days of the prior date, before or after. So I need to use Datetime.

Basically, I want to do this:
select fail cases number from the output result

```
=> output_sheet[output_sheet[output_result =='FAIL']]
  => get the results in some array or vector  **(how ? )**
```

go to input_sheet, do

`=> input_df.groupBy(input_carId)`
=> `replace the failing dates with a new unique date within +-7k days of that old date`

but it has to be **unique** date for that input_carId. So I think I need to use `unique()`.

I cannot use the output_df as input_df; they're 2 very different sheets. I greatly simplified their schema here, they only share 3 columns. And also, they actually are +20000 such rows and ids

In the end I have the old input_df but changed with the new dates.

**output_df**

```
case_id        output_date        output_carId   ouput_result
1                 01/20/21             001          FAIL
2                 02/21/21             001          SUCCESS  
3                 02/08/20             003          FAIL 
4                 01/07/20             001          FAIL
5                 09/05/20             002          SUCCESS
```

**input_df** (old)

```
case_id    input_date         input_carId  
    1          01/20/21             001  
    2          02/21/21             002 
    3          02/08/20             003
    4          01/07/20             001
    5          09/05/20             002
```

expected result  =>

****input_df** (new)**

```
   case_id   input_date         input_carId  
    1          01/13/21             001  
    2          02/21/21             002 
    3          02/22/20             003
    4          01/28/20             001
    5          09/05/20             002
```

Notice the dates for the failed cases rows 1,3,4 have changed by -+ multiple of 7 days

Comment: How looks expected output? Are in sample data matching +-7 days?

Comment: Can you please clarify. Do you wish to to generate a new dataframe with a unique date?  Also, what makes a "unique row" in the output_df or input_df? Is it car_Id + Date? Otherwise, the problem is not well defined..

Comment: @supercooler8 I want to edit the input dataframe with those new dates. For each carId I need a set of dates. They all need to be different. So for instance for carID 001, if I do a groupBy the rows for this carId should all have different dates. I only need to change the dates which have failed.

Comment: @jezrael  The expected ouput is a new input sheet with the dates fixed for the failed cases

Comment: I think how looks data in new DataFrame from sample data in question.

Comment: @jezrael the new dataframe is simply the old input dataframe but now with new dates.

Comment: How looks new dates? What is changed? How is possible verify some solution?

Comment: @jezrael To verify the dates I need to do an http post call and use `concurrent_futures` to call an API because there are so many dates

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - It seems we dont underdstand each other. I think if possible change sample data in question for `+-7 days` and then add manually expcted ouput (exaclty how looks `output_df` after changed datetimes). If working solution correct, then apply it to real data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229036/discussion-between-unixvanxcel-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function for add +- 7 days to rows with `FAIL`:

```
output_df['output_date'] = pd.to_datetime(output_df['output_date'])
input_df['input_date'] = pd.to_datetime(input_df['input_date'])

cases = output_df.loc[output_df['ouput_result'] =='FAIL', 'case_id']
print (cases)
0    1
2    3
3    4
Name: case_id, dtype: int64

def func(dates):

    #count number of failed rows
    count = len(dates)
    
    #generate range by count of failed rows, multiple 7 (omited 0)
    arr = np.arange(1, count + 1) * 7
    #shuffling for random
    np.random.shuffle(arr)
    #generated timedeltas for add or subtract
    td = pd.to_timedelta(arr, unit='d')
    less = dates - td
    more = dates + td
    #randomly add or subtract
    rand = np.random.randint(2, size=count, dtype=bool)

    #return +- 7 days
    return np.where(rand, less, more)

#filter by cases
mask = input_df['case_id'].isin(cases)
input_df.loc[mask, 'input_date'] = (input_df[mask].groupby('input_carId')['input_date']
                                                  .transform(func))
```

---

```
print (input_df)
   case_id input_date  input_carId
0        1 2021-02-03            1
1        2 2021-02-21            2
2        3 2020-02-15            3
3        4 2020-01-14            1
4        5 2020-09-05            2
```

Comment: first Thank you. But I do not want to merge input_df and output_df. I want to have the old separate input_df but with the new dates.

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - Hmmm, I only guess what need, because cannot verify my solution :(

Comment: The final result that I need is a new input_df with the new dates, that way i can run the tests again with a new input_df. Does that make sense?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel Can you explain what is wrong?

Comment: we want to fix the rows in input_df which have a wrong date and then return input_df. Input_df and Ouput_df have the same order, so when you find the failed rows from output_df you need to go to input_df. 
Now, you need to do a groupBy(input_carId) and you have different  groups. For example, Mercedes, Ford, etc... For each group, you need to correct the failed rows if they have by choosing a new unique date, and in the end return the entire dataframe input_df

Comment: 1)  from output_df get the caseIDs which are failing                                                                                                 

2)  from input_df do groupBy(input_CarId)

3)  in each group, if there is a failed case, then generate a new unique date

4) return new input_df with same format as old input_df but with new dates

Comment: right now, your solution only creates new rows -thats all it does

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - Answer was changed, can you test?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - Super! Let me know how working.

Comment: Thank you! it looks good, only you did not do the unique() part; each groupBy( case_id) needs to have a SET of dates. Right now we could have duplicates

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - Is possible be more specific? Why solution not working?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel unique datetimes has to be only new added values per groups? Or unique new + old not changed datetimes ?

Comment: yes unique in new + old for each groupBy(case_id)

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - Really not easy, is possible duplicates in original datetimes?

Comment: hmm no, there shouldn't be duplicates in the original input_df.you can assume there are no duplicates in original input_df. Is it easier that way for you?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - How is tested duplicates? What return `print (input_df[input_df.duplicated(['input_date','input_carId'])])` after my solution?

Comment: everytime you create a new date for a case_id example case_id1 ; you can check if it already exists in input_df.groupBy(case_id1)

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - Not possible, because cannot seen rows not matched `case_id1`, also values are count by `+-td` so how test it?

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - So I think still is simpliest use something like `test duplicates` and if found, add or remove `7` check again until no duplicates

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - So what return `print (input_df[input_df.duplicated(['input_date','input_carId'])])` ?

Comment: it just calls "find new date" again

Comment: @uniXVanXcel - Sorry, why if I ask for something you there is answer for something else? What return `print (input_df[input_df.duplicated(['input_date','input_carId'])]) ? ` in real data?

Comment: it returns the duplicate rows in the group case_id[i] with the same dates